# Whats the faster algorithm to rearrange given array of numbers

Tags: python, algorithm

The question is from code fight which states: An infinite number of boxes are arranged in a row and numbered from left to right. The first box on the left is
number 1, the next box is number 2, etc. n balls are placed in n of the boxes, and there can only be one ball per box.
You want to organize the balls, so you decide to arrange all the balls next to each other. They should occupy a
contiguous set of boxes. You can take one ball and move it into an empty box in one move.

Given an array balls that indicates the numbers of the boxes in which the balls are placed, find the minimum number of
moves needed to organize the balls.

Example

For balls = [6, 4, 1, 7, 10], the output should be
ballsRearranging(balls) = 2.

In this example, the minimum number of moves needed to arrange the balls next to each other is 2. You could move the
ball in box 1 to box 5 and the ball in box 10 to box 8 (or to box 3).

Currently my code is:

```
def ballsRearranging(balls):
    ballsLength = len(balls)
    partial = ballsLength//2 #INITIALLY SET TO HALF
    setBalls = set(balls)
    sortedBalls = sorted(balls)
    minimum = 1000000

    #####CHECK IF ITS ALREADY ORGANIZED
    #####FIRST NUM PLUS LENGTH - 1 IS EQUAL TO THE LAST NUM
    if sortedBalls[0]+ballsLength-1 == sortedBalls[-1]:
        return 0

    for i,num in enumerate(sortedBalls):
        #####NO NEED TO GO PASS HALF WAY SINCE THAT AUTOMATICALLY MEANS HALF WILL BE OUT OF RANGE
        #####THIS VALUE DYNAMICALLY CHANGES TO THE SMALLEST FRACTION OF OUT OF RANGE FOUND
        if i >= partial:
            break

        #####IF WE TAKE THIS NUM AS THE BEGINNING, ORDERED BALLS WILL GO UP TO THE RANGE RNG
        rng = range(num,num+ballsLength)
        #####BALLS ALREADY IN THE RANGE RNG, WE WONT BE MOVING THESE BALLS
        inRange = setBalls & set(rng)

        #####BALLS NOT IN RANGE, EACH WILL BE REQUIRED TO MOVE
        #####THE LENGTH OF THIS WILL BE THE NUMBER OF MOVES REQUIRED
        outRange = setBalls - set(rng)

        lenOutRange = len(outRange)
        if lenOutRange < minimum:
            minimum = lenOutRange
            partial = 100*(lenOutRange/ballsLength) #UPDATE THE PARTIAL VALUE
```

This works fine but currently times out with the time limit of 4s on the hidden tests.  Basically my algorithm goes from the smallest number to a specific partial (fraction) of the given array.  It checks where the original set intersects with the given range.  Whichever has the least amount of out of range items, will be the minimum number of changes/rearranging to be made.  Was wondering whats the better algorithm, preferably in python.

Comment: What's the big O complexity for this current algorithm?

Comment: I suggest that you move this to CodeReview.StackExchange.com; StackOverflow is generally for non-working code.

Comment: For help here, please post the driver code for a long-running test case.

Comment: `print balls_rearranging(range(0, 10000000, 2))` is a good test case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code is careful to compute the result in O(n log n) time. Or if the balls are already sorted, this runs in O(n) time.

It uses a caterpillar algorithm: for each j, indexed into the sorted array of balls, i is incremented until it contains the first ball within `n-1` of the ball at index j. That makes it easy to count the number of balls in the range that ends with the j'th ball.

```
def balls_rearranging(balls):
    balls.sort()
    best = 0
    i = 0
    for j in xrange(len(balls)):
        while balls[i] <= balls[j] - len(balls):
            i += 1
        best = max(best, j - i + 1)
    return len(balls) - best

print balls_rearranging(range(0, 10000000, 2))
```

Answer (score 2):

a Java version for the code contributed by paul-hankin

```
int ballsRearranging(int[] balls) {
Arrays.sort(balls); // sort the array
int i = 0;
int j = 0;
int max = 0;
for(j = 0; j < balls.length;j++) {
    while(balls[i] <= balls[j] - balls.length) {
        i++;
    }
    max = Math.max(max,j-i+1);
}
return balls.length - max;}
```

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you're burning a lot of time with your range and set constructions.  Quit checking actual ball locations and empty boxes.  All you need is the quantity of moves, not the actual balls to be moved.

For instance, given something like [1, 2, 100, 103, 104, 106, 9998, 9999], you don't care *what* those four outliers are, or which boxes are empty in the low-100 range.  All you need is the quantity, 4.

The solution reduces to something simpler:

```
size = len(balls)
balls.sort()
for box in balls:
    # How many balls are in the range box : box+size-1 ?
    # retain the maximum of these values
return size - maximum   # number of empty boxes in that range
```

If you're a little stubborn about it, you can reduce this to a single line.